# Outlook: reply all removes the attachment

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, attachments

I am using Outlook 2010. When I forward an email the attachment is also forwarded.
But when reply all and add someone else to the email the attachment is removed - can that been changed so the attachment is also included for reply all?

Comment: Unless the file is changed is there a reason to resend the attachment to the original group?  If not, and everyone is doing this same thing, mailboxes can get big and big Outlook boxes are not stable.  If you don't have to duplicate attachments your IT department will thank you.  Perhaps forwarding the email to the new recipient with attachment then replying all and adding that person to the chain w/out attachement?

Comment: I am replying but at same time adding new people in cc so they need the attachment.

Answer (score 1):

The only real built-in setting available is in `File > Options > Mail > Replies and Forwards` change the option next to `When replying to a message:` choose to `Attach original message`.

This attaches the entire original message, including attachments. The downside is that it is sent as a `msg` attachment needing to be opened with Outlook.

There are other ways to accomplish this, though they require more work.

- Forward and readdress
- Resend the message (requires address changes)
- Use a VBA macro to reply with attachments
- Use an add-in

[Source](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/564)